# Error declaring varchar variable inside MySQL Function

Tags: mysql, mysql-variables, mysql-function

I am attempting to create a MySQL variable inside a stored function similar to this:

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER
FUNCTION t_func(cc char(2), lc char(2), os varchar(1000))
    RETURNS varchar(1000)
    DETERMINISTIC
    READS SQL DATA
BEGIN

    DECLARE mytext VARCHAR(1000);
    SET mytext = NULL;

    -- Other stuff follows...

    RETURN mytext;

END;;
```

But I get this error complaining about the DECLARE line:

> [Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near '' at line 8

How do you declare a variable inside a MySQL function? According to the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/declare.html) on `DECLARE` syntax, I am following all of the placement rules.

Comment: I know this is probably going to be something stupid simple and overlooked. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: `the right syntax to use near '' at line 8` ...when the error is reported to be near *empty string*, this means the parser is at the end of the input buffer... which means you didn't use a `DELIMITER` statement to change the statement delimiter from `;` to something else -- `;;` is probably what you were planning, based on `END;;` so the client is only sending up through line 8.

Comment: <Head Slap> Thank you! New is was something simple. If you make it into an answer I will gladly accept it.

Comment: Thank you for offering me the option of posting an answer, but I think this is one we can close as a problem that can no longer be reproduced or simple typographical error.